# Why does Maven exclude application.properties on project update and how can I disable this behavior?

Tags: spring-boot, eclipse, maven

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEjCB.png)
When I do update maven project it sets src/main/resources
Excluded : **

How can I stop this behavior?
I have to manually set it to None everytime.

I tried creating project using Spring initializer but it didn't work as well.

Comment: This _Java Build Path_ setting does not exclude `application.properties` from being copied to the output folder. It exclude all .java files in `/src/main/resources` to be compiled (= exclude them from the _Java Build Path_). Only Java file in `/src/main/java` will be compiled and the .class files will be copied into the output folder. In contrast, Java files in `/src/main/resources` will not be compiled, but just copied into the output folder. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Does your build work on plain command line? If so than it's fine... the things shown in Eclipse is a different thing....